# Removing NA values and creating new columns when reshaping a dataframe

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following example df. The actual df have 80 rows and 10 columns:

```
Fruits  PRS_001_Person_ABCD  PRS_002_Person_ABCD  PRS_015_Person_ABCD  PRS_016_Person_ABCD
Apple       0.5                  1.3                  NA                   NA
Orange      0.2                  NA                   0.021                NA
Grape       NA                   0.06                 NA                   0.7
Berry       NA                   NA                   0.3                  0.04
Apple       NA                   1.3                  0.5                  NA
```

I would like to have the following data frame:

```
Fruits     Value1    Value2    Person1       Person2
Apple      0.5       1.3       Product 1     Product 2         
Orange     0.2       0.021     Product 1     Product 15 
Grape      0.06      0.7       Product 2     Product 16
Berry      0.3       0.04      Product 15    Product 16
Apple      1.3       0.5       Product 2     Product 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(rn,Fruits), values_to = "Value", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Person = paste("Product", 
                        str_remove(str_extract(name, "[[:digit:]]+"),"^0+"))) %>% 
  group_by(Fruits, rn) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(-name, names_from = row, values_from = c(Value, Person), names_sep = "") %>% 
  ungroup %>% select(-rn)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   Fruits Value1 Value2 Person1    Person2   
#>   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1 Apple    0.5   1.3   Product 1  Product 2 
#> 2 Orange   0.2   0.021 Product 1  Product 15
#> 3 Grape    0.06  0.7   Product 2  Product 16
#> 4 Berry    0.3   0.04  Product 15 Product 16
#> 5 Apple    1.3   0.5   Product 2  Product 15
```

#### Data:

```
read.table(text = "Fruits   PRS_001_Person_ABCD     PRS_002_Person_ABCD    PRS_015_Person_ABCD     PRS_016_Person_ABCD
 Apple       0.5                    1.3                     NA                     NA
 Orange      0.2                    NA                      0.021                  NA
 Grape       NA                     0.06                    NA                     0.7
 Berry       NA                     NA                      0.3                    0.04
 Apple       NA                     1.3                     0.5                    NA          ", 
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE) -> df1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question, adding a new row where the fruit is repeated but the values are changed. Can you please edit your answer according to the updated question.

Comment: @Sarah not a good practice to change your question after you get an answer. I edited my answer to address your problem, but next time, you should post another question and refer to the original one if you have a follow up question or have a different case/data to work with. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(hacksaw)
df1 %>% 
 mutate(across(-Fruits,
   ~ case_when(!is.na(.x)~  sprintf("Product %d", 
   readr::parse_number(cur_column()))), .names = "Person_{.col}")) %>% 
   unite(Person, starts_with("Person"), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(Person, delim = '_', names = c("Person1", "Person2")) %>% 
  relocate(matches("Person\\d+"), .after = Fruits) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  shift_row_values() %>%
  rename_with(~ str_c("Value", seq_along(.x)), contains("_")) %>% 
  select(Fruits, starts_with("Value"), starts_with("Person"),
      -where(~ all(is.na(.x)))) %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  Fruits Value1 Value2 Person1    Person2   
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
1 Apple    0.5   1.3   Product 1  Product 2 
2 Orange   0.2   0.021 Product 1  Product 15
3 Grape    0.06  0.7   Product 2  Product 16
4 Berry    0.3   0.04  Product 15 Product 16
5 Apple    1.3   0.5   Product 2  Product 15
```